# VS2012: xcopy error with cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a solution on VS 2012 that has been building without errors, then out of no where the build started failing with the following error :

```
    Error   106 error MSB3073: The command "if not exist "C:\Workspace\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\tools\project-creator\undefined\proj.win32\Debug.win32\" mkdir "C:\Workspace\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\tools\project-creator\undefined\proj.win32\Debug.win32\"
xcopy /Y /Q "C:\Workspace\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\tools\project-creator\undefined\proj.win32\..\..\..\external\libwebsockets\win32\lib\*.*" "C:\Workspace\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\tools\project-creator\undefined\proj.win32\Debug.win32\"
:VCEnd" exited with code 4. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  129 5   undeifned
```

This solution is created by Cocos2d-x tool.
How to fix bug ?

Answer (score 0):

The encrypted message mean the folder/files are in use.

I just have the same error a few minutes ago.

1. Close all the program and reopen.
2. Reboot if the above failed.